# Spotipy: simple code from readthedocs got exception

Tags: python, spotipy

When I run this simple code from [Spotify's Docs](http://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#):

```
import spotipy

birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
spotify = spotipy.Spotify()

results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

I got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haodong/Documents/Projects/python-workspace/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 119, in _internal_call
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/haodong/Documents/Projects/python-workspace/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 844, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=artist%3ARadiohead&offset=0&type=artist&limit=10

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    results = spotify.search(q='artist:' + name, type='artist')
  File "/Users/haodong/Documents/Projects/python-workspace/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 339, in search
    return self._get('search', q=q, limit=limit, offset=offset, type=type, market=market)
  File "/Users/haodong/Documents/Projects/python-workspace/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 146, in _get
    return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/Users/haodong/Documents/Projects/python-workspace/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 124, in _internal_call
    headers=r.headers)
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 401, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=artist%3ARadiohead&offset=0&type=artist&limit=10:
 No token provided
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your Spotify app credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) from www.developer.spotify.com, assign it to a variable and use that as your object.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

cid ="Your-client-ID" 
secret = "Your-client-secret"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

#Then run your query
results = sp.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album'))

#### ETC ######
```

More info here: [Client Credential Flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#client-credentials-flow)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spotify Web API has been updated recently and requires authorization for all kinds of requests.

Use [authorized requests](http://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorized-requests) would solve this problem.